# How can i Popup a NSMenu in a custom views in NSMenuItems?

Tags: swift, macos, popup, view, nsmenu

I have a NSMenu with a custom views, just like this.

> ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var theMenu: NSMenu!
    @IBOutlet var theMenuItem: NSMenuItem!
    @IBOutlet var customView: NSView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        theMenuItem.view = customView
    }

    @IBAction func showTheMenuWithCustomView(_ sender: NSButton) {
        // Popup the menu below button
        let position = NSPoint(x: 0, y: sender.frame.height+2)
        theMenu.popUp(positioning: nil, at: position, in: sender)
    }

 }
```

This works well.

But in custom views, i need to popup an another menu. After i call the popUp method, it just show nothing. Here is the code:

> CustomView.swift

```
class CustomView: NSView {

    @IBAction func showCustomViewMenu(_ sender: NSButton) {
        // Create the menu in custom view
        let customViewMenu = NSMenu()
        // Add a menu item in it
        customViewMenu.addItem(withTitle: "no one care", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
        // Popup the menu below button
        let position = NSPoint(x: 0, y: sender.frame.height+2)
        customViewMenu.popUp(positioning: nil, at: position, in: sender)
    }

 }
```

You can clone this project to test it:

https://github.com/Caldis/NSMenuQuestion

**How can i Popup NSMenu in custom views in NSMenuItems ?**

Answer (score 0):

Use this line to show the additional popup on CustomView:

```
NSMenu.popUpContextMenu(customViewMenu, with: NSApp.currentEvent!, for: sender)
```

Additionally, if you also need to disable other popups on whole `CustomView`, override `rightMouseDown` in `CustomView`, like so:

```
class CustomView: NSView {
    override func rightMouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```